# next line for a html code on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have here my jquery (coffeescript)

```
    if value.kind != 'Quasi-Judicial'
      if value.court_agency !in court_agency_with_branch
        if value.court_agency != 'Department of Justice'
          @court_agency  = "<option value=\"" + value.id + "\"> Branch "+ value.branch_division + ", " + value.court_agency + ", " + @city_or_municipality + ", " + value.province + "</option>"              
        else
          @court_agency  = "<option value=\"" + value.id + "\">" + value.court_agency + ", " + @city_or_municipality + ", " + value.province + "</option>"
      else
          @court_agency  = "<option value=\"" + value.id + "\"> Division "+ value.branch_division + ", " + value.court_agency + "</option>"              
    else
      @court_agency  = "<option value=\"" + value.id + "\">" + value.department + ", " + value.govt_agency + ", " + @city_or_municipality + ", " + value.province + "</option>"
```

on this part

```
"<option value=\"" + value.id + "\">" + value.department + ", " + value.govt_agency + ", " + @city_or_municipality + ", " + value.province + "</option>"
```

I want to put some code `\n`

```
"<option value=\"" + value.id + "\">" + value.department + ", " + "\n" + value.govt_agency + ", " + @city_or_municipality + ", " + value.province + "</option>"
```

but nothing happens.

The value looks like:

```
Department of Blah blah, City of This thing, Province of this stuff
```

What possible code I can use to create an output like this:

```
Department of Blah blah,
City of This thing,
Province of this stuff
```

Comment: Oh, what did I wrong? I thought I asking with other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Can you have multiple lines in an <option> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746824/can-you-have-multiple-lines-in-an-option-element).
(What you're looking for is a br tag in an option tag)

Comment: because it's not permitted : http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/option.html. Maybe you should try with some jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this demo 
http://shyalika.com/mutiline_select_example

you can find more information here: 
http://shyalika.com/multiline_select_control